# HTML code only shows {{title}} instead of variable name

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm currently following this tuturial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlAq06Z_25Y&list=PL8p2I9GklV45JZerGMvw5JVxPSxCg8VPv&index=4

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Vh6.png)

but html only shows

[what i get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB5VN.png)

i'm trying to learn angular but it's verry confusing if you try to follow a turturial but some things just dont match up

code:

app.module.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'blog';
}
```

app.component.html code:

```
<h1>Hello World !</h1>
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
```

app.component.spec.ts code:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'blog'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('blog');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('blog app is running!');
  });
});
```

Comment: is there any error in the console ?

Comment: share your component.ts and component.html

Comment: Please show the code you're attempting.

Comment: app.component.ts code: 'import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'blog app';
}
'

Comment: You put TypeScript in the CSS and JavaScript boxes of the snippet. That's not going to work (as you can see when you click Run code snippet).

Comment: no errors in the concole

Comment: _“i'm trying to learn angular but it's verry confusing if you try to follow a turturial but some things just dont match up”_ - that’s what you get, when you only “watch” tutorials. Those rarely ever cover all you need to know, and “skipping” to find the correct part is also much harder, than if you were _reading up_ on stuff in the first place.

Comment: Where are you opening the app? If you're opening the .html file directly in a browser obviously it'll be rendered as is. Angular apps should be served from a server. If you're using `ng serve` to test the app it's served in `http://localhost:4200` by default. You need to open this URL instead of directly opening the file.

Comment: Also if you're new, I'd highly recommend going their [official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). It's fairly short and introduces many basics of the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your app with `ng serve` and then verify your output on `localhost:4200`.
In case you need to run it on any other port, use `ng serve --port:portnumber`

Comment: Use https://angular.io/tutorial for better understanding of angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a public method to pass it between your components:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public title = "blog";
}

<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
```

Comment: Tried it but doesn't seem to work

https://i.imgur.com/ZoybPCe.png

Comment: Check the console if it shows you an error, the communication between the component and the selector is not working

Comment: don't see anything in the concole....

https://i.imgur.com/9RZkjJs.png

Comment: Do the following:
1. Create a home.component
2. In the app-routing create a constant and add the HomeComponent class ``const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: HomeComponent}
];``
3. Add your html app to home.html and your ts app to home.ts
4. In the html app just put <router-outlet> </router-outlet>

Answer (score 0):

**i used port 5200 but i should use port 4200 instead. now it works**